# How to compare attribute in other table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have two table :

**table 1:**

```
users
========+===========
user_id | user_name
--------+-----------
1       | bn
2       | gn
3       | en
```

**table 2:**

```
user_attr
========+===========+=============
user_id | attr_name | attr_value
--------+-----------+-------------
1       | sell      | 1
2       | first     | 245
1       | au        | 246
2       | sell      | 1
```

In PostgreSQL I want the user id from table users who doesn't have a `'au'`,`'first'` or `'sell'` in `user_attr` table .

**I tested below query but not work :**

```
SELECT users.user_id
FROM users 
    INNER JOIN user_attrs ON users.user_id = user_attrs.user_id 
WHERE
    users.group_id = '$group' AND (user_attrs.attr_name != 'first' 
    AND user_attrs.attr_name != 'sell' AND user_attrs.attr_name != 'au') 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: i've tried your query and it works for me ,the only difference between you and me is the users.group_id which you didn't mention. And according to your e.g, the result will be null is that what you want?

Comment: no i want user_id 3 user who no first no sell no au attr

Answer (score 1):

I get what problem you got. If the data is the same as you gave us, it's very simple, you use inner join and attrs table only got user_id =1 and 2. so you got nothing. just try left join:

```
SELECT users.user_id FROM users 
    LEFT JOIN user_attrs ON users.user_id = user_attrs.user_id 
WHERE users.group_id = '$group'
   AND (user_attrs.attr_name != 'first' 
   AND user_attrs.attr_name != 'sell'
   AND user_attrs.attr_name != 'au') 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT users.user_id 
      FROM users 
INNER JOIN user_attrs ON users.user_id = user_attrs.user_id 
     WHERE users.group_id = '$group' 
       AND user_attrs.attr_name NOT IN ('first','au','sell') LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: what output you get ?

Comment: all output same and one user_id

Comment: it's working in my case can u tell me where group_id is come from